# Setting event date in views

Tags: views, datetime

i have events page on my Drupal and it is showing events until the relative date (is greater than) "now" which means the event disappears from the table on the starting date of the event.

Can you please help me with setting that date **to the last day of the event** - so that the event stays on the table until the last day. I have multiple events, so i really dont know how to do this. I checked other relative formats, but i am no developer, so i am puzzled.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your node contains Date field than you can set start and end date (you can turn on/off end date field in field settings). Both are available in Views so instead of building your Views filter on start date, build it on end date.

Comment: Thank you for very this logical answer. Solved my problem.